# How to add Attachment in Infopath2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-2013

How to add attachment field in infopath2013? I searched this problem on internet and all are saying to find it on home>Controls>Object but I cant find Attachment on This path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DATA in the top ribbon, click SHOW FIELDS (if the list of available fields isn't already visible).  In this list, you should see the option for the field "Attachments", with the paper clip symbol to the left of it.

Comment: No Its not showing anything like Attachment . But I have one doubt. Do I have to create Attachment field on SharePoint first? Or I can create or directly add Attachment here on InfoPath.

Comment: I am assuming you are customizing a SharePoint list form using InfoPath. Check the list of fields on the right. You should see the attachments field. Drag and drop it on the place where you want it to be on the form

Comment: No, you don't have to create the field - It's automatically generated.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. The mistake that I had done was I didn't set Enable Attachment in the advanced setting.

Comment: Ah - I'd guessed you had already done so.  But now you know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

We will get the attachment control in the below navigation :
Menus > Insert(ribbon 2nd row) >Control > File Attachment

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to a list->Customize form, then you can see attachments field in InfoPath:

[image]